# Why does my WCF service keep defaulting to http?

Tags: wcf, web-services, visual-studio-2008, https, soapui

I configured my WCF service to https.  I can browse WSDL using my https:// url address.  However, when I test the service using SOAP UI, the URL deafults to http.  I do receive expected response when I test it.  If I change the URL in SOAP UI to https, I get the following.

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 04 Dec 2012 16:46:32 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

This question is related to my other question:
[Why my WSDL still shows basic http binding with the location value of http?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13502185/why-my-wsdl-still-shows-basic-http-binding-with-the-location-value-of-http)

Any ideas??  Is this a problem with IIS configuration?

Comment: Please post your config file.

Comment: It is in the question linked to this question.

Comment: Pull up your WSDL and see what URL is present there.  SoapUI will use that URL.

Comment: WSDL has http url.  But I configured both my IIS and WCF to use https.  As per my previous question's answer, it is the IIS that provides correct URL.

Comment: But your WSDL is what is read to setup the SoapUI client.  It should contain your https URL if that's where the client should be going.

Comment: That was my original question.  If so, how do I get https in my WSDL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to fix it by changing wsHttpBinding to basicHttpBinding.  Everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your (only) problem since you haven't posted your configuration, but you need HttpsGetEnabled set to true and also need to use an https base address.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751498.aspx

Comment: Config file is in the question linked to this question.